# I want to work with variables in my less file but it didn't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, xhtml, less

I want to integrate lesscss in my JavaEE project in order to customize my facelets components. 
I did follow many guide and i downloaded less.js from Lesscss.org and i put it under js folder wich is either under resources folder. then I created a less file as follow :

```
.shape{
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:#ddf;
margin:20px;}
```

this is where it's called in my index.xhtml

```
 <div class="shape" id="shape1"></div>
                        <div class="shape" id="shape2"></div>
                         <div class="shape" id="shape3"></div> 

                <rich:panel  styleClass="shape" style="float:left; width:200px; padding:5px;">
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                             <h:outputText value="gfhgfh" style="font-weight:bold" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </f:facet>
                   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="State Capital :" style="font-weight:bold" />
                        <h:outputText value="#fghfghf" />
                        <h:outputText value="State TimeZone :" style="font-weight:bold" />
                        <h:outputText value="fezgzeg" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </rich:panel>
```

the code above works well with Mozilla browser. but, when i put a less variable in my less file like :

```
@lightBlue:#ddf;
.shape{
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:@lightBlue;
margin:20px;
```

}

it doesen't work and nothing displays. and by the way . I have always this error in my apacheTomcat.

```
ATTENTION: JSF1091 : Aucun type mime détecté pour le fichier style.less.  Pour résoudre ce problème, ajoutez un mappage mime-type au fichier web.xml de l’application.
```

Anyone cal help plz ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add LESS file mime type in web.xml in your project.

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>less</extension>
  <mime-type>stylesheet/less</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```